# Adding a number to a filename if the file already exist while copying. in batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, double

How do I Add a number to a filename if the filename already exist while copying. in a batchfile?

i already have this:

`for /r "%cd%" %%a in (*.wav) do copy "%%a" "output"`

i use windows 7

Comment: You need to use a `loop` and `if exist` to determine if a number already exists, and to increment the number until you get a number that doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add a random number to each filename.

```
@echo off
for /r "%cd%" %%a in (*.wav) do call copy "%%a" "output\%%~na-%%random%%%%random%%%%~xa"
pause
```

Comment: Can it also be counting numbers instead of random numbers? if the file already exist, like:  Sound-1.wav Sound-2.wav Sound-3.wav etc..